# DivisionFreeRowReduction Method for RowReduce

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

My overall goal is to use a division free algorithm to compute the nullspace of a matrix containing multivariate polynomials. For doing so, I believe, there is the method `DivisionFreeRowReduction` which can be also used for `RowReduce`. However, it seems to not actually do division free row reduction. Here are two examples:

```
M = {{x, x + y}, {y, 2*y}};
RowReduce[M, Method -> "DivisionFreeRowReduction"]
```

yields the identity matrix whereas one might expect something like
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x & x+y \\ y & 2y\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} x & x+y \\ xy & 2xy\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} x & x+y \\ 0 & xy-2xy^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

The same is even true over the integres:

```
M2 = {{2, 3}, {4, 4}};
RowReduce[M2, Method -> "DivisionFreeRowReduction"]
```

yields the identity matrix, so it seems to divide.

What is going on? Why does the division free row reduction divide? How can you compute a nullspace using division free methods?

Comment: It does the forward reduction without division, then uses division to get pivots of 1, as this is required to produce the row echelon form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! So for integers I could use of course `HermiteDecomposition` to get a reduced form without any divisions. Is anyone aware of a method to compute the nullspace truly division free? To me it seems a bit misleading if `Nullspace[M,Method->"DivisionFreeRowReduction"]` does divide.

Answer (score 3):

Try appending the Identity matrix to `M` and apply the row reduction to the larger matrix to recover the composite of the elementary row reductions:

```
Mprime = Join[M, IdentityMatrix[2], 2];
rrt = RowReduce[Mprime][[;; , 3 ;; 4]]
```

Then extract all of the divisions that were used in the row reduction:

```
denom = PolynomialLCM @@ Flatten[Denominator[rrt]]
```

Then undo the divisions that were used in the row reduction by clearing denominators:

```
rrtNoDivision=Simplify[denom*rrt]
```

The "no division" result you are seeking is
`rrtNoDivision.M` using the row reduction transform `rrtNoDivision`.